# NullReferenceException when referencing element if I execute InitializeComponent on parent class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Edit:** It's incorrectly marked a duplicate because it's not about identifying the `NullReferenceException` or even understanding what it is... It's about figuring out why an extended native `InitializeComponent()` call would make the upper class's XAML elements unable to be referenced. Why does that specific super call cause the NullReference. Hopefully someone capable of seeing the difference will understand. Thank you.

---

I have a `MyPage->BasePage->ContentPage` structure. If `BasePage` executes `InitializeComponent()` then the XAML elements lose scope within `MyPage`.. meaning I can't call `MyPage.MyListView.ItemSource = xyz` without getting a NullReferenceException.

If I disable the `InitializeComponent()` call from within `BasePage`, then it works as expected.

What is the `BasePage.InitializeComponent()` doing that breaks the scope above?

```
   Models
   Pages
     ├ BasePage.xaml
     |   ⤷ BasePage.xaml.cs
     └ MyPage.xaml
         ⤷ MyPage.xaml.cs
   Views
   App.xaml
     ⤷ App.xaml.cs
```

On my `MyPage.xaml` markup, I have various StackLayout elements, ListView, etc. It all exists within a `pages:BasePage.Content` tag, like so:

```
<!-- for s/o: MyPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:BasePage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Namespace.Pages"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Namespace.Views"
    x:Class="Namespace.Pages.MyPage">

    <pages:BasePage.Content>

        <ListView x:Name="ListViewView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding imageUrl}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding formattedDayOfWeek}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding formattedDate}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </pages:BasePage.Content>

</pages:BasePage>
```

Within my `MyPage.xaml.cs` class, the constructor executes the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Here's what the `BasePage.xaml` looks like:

```
<!-- for s/o: BasePage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Namespace.Pages.BasePage"
    x:Name="_parent">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="VerticalLayout" BackgroundColor="#f1f1f1">
            <ContentView
                x:Name="cv"
                x:FieldModifier="public"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Content="{Binding Path=ViewContent, Source={x:Reference _parent}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

---

So to reiterate:

Within the `MyPage.xaml.cs`, I'm trying to call `ListViewView.ItemsSource = SomeDataModel` after an async fetch from a REST server.

If the extended `BasePage.xaml.cs` class calls `InitializeComponent()` in its constructor... I will get a NullReferenceException when setting the ItemsSource.

If the extended `BasePage.xaml.cs` class DOES NOT call `InitializeComponent()` in its constructor... The ItemsSource is correctly set and the list appears.

Can someone explain to me what's happening here so I can successfully initialize everything? If I don't initialize the BasePage, then I can't access elements on it as I'd want to.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code? :)

Comment: _"This isn't about understanding what a NullReferenceException is"_ -- then, present your question without mentioning `NullReferenceException`. A question that is truly not asking about the exception would not need to mention it, and _would_ include information explaining what you found when you investigated the NRE, and also _would_ include a good [mcve] reproducing the problem.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterDuniho There's a difference between asking what a NullReferenceException is and why it's being thrown.  The question is basically, _Why is X null here?_--except we don't know what X is, and we don't know where "here" is.  This shouldn't be closed as a duplicate, but Matt, you're going to have to at least provide a stack trace and the code it references, even if it's automatically generated.

Comment: @Zenexer: _"There's a difference between asking what a NullReferenceException is and why it's being thrown"_ -- no, there's not. It's _always_ thrown for the same reason: the code tried to dereference a null reference. Only once someone has gotten _past_ that, and can ask their question without mentioning the NRE _and_ the question is more than "why is this null?", have they investigated enough to push the question to the SO community. And when they do, they need to provide a good, well-written question with a good [mcve], just like everyone else should.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree that the question is lacking, but it can be a good question while still mentioning NRE--and I'd rather that Matt keep the mention of NRE, as I'd like to see a stack trace.  I also agree that Matt is asking the wrong question here, but it doesn't make sense to mark it as a dupe--he's very clearly not intending to ask what an NRE is.  He seems to be running into trouble because he's under the impression that InitializeComponent is guaranteed to avoid throwing an NRE and isn't sure how to proceed with debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, BasePage's constructor is being called prior to MyPage's constructor.  This also means that BasePage's InitializeComponent will be called before MyPage's constructor.

The call order is going to effectively look like this, so what's actually happening under-the-hood is slightly different:

1. `BasePage..ctor`
2. `BasePage.InitializeComponent`
3. `MyPage..ctor`
4. `MyPage.InitializeComponent`

This creates a dependency issue: nothing in BasePage's InitializeComponent method can depend on anything that's initialized by MyPage.  If it does, you'll likely get a `NullReferenceException` or other unintended behavior.

It's hard to know exactly what the source of your error is without seeing your C# code, but I strongly suspect `BasePage.InitializeComponent` is referencing something that's not set until `MyPage..ctor` or `MyPage.InitializeComponent` runs.  You can easily test this by temporarily removing the call to `BasePage.InitializeComponent` in `BasePage..ctor` and moving it to the end of `MyPage.InitializeComponent`.

Comment: I understand that order which is why I'm confused. My `BasePage.xaml.cs` doesn't even reference anything in its own XAML for demo purposes; it just calls `InitializeComponent` in the constructor. The `MyPage.xaml.cs` ONLY references an element within the `MyPage.xaml`... it doesn't call anything in BasePage. That's why I'm so confused, because I have them limited to their own scopes but when I let `BasePage` call `InitializeComponent` in its constructor.. then `MyPage` seems to forget what its scope is.

Comment: BasePage.InitializeComponent definitely isn't empty, and that's almost certainly where you're getting the NRE.  However, if you don't provide the contents of InitializeComponent and the stack trace, I can't help you any further.